# Weird behaviour with SSIS 2008 and XSD's with maxOccurs attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the same problem mentioned below and I hope someone can help with this.

---

Has anyone used an XSD that contains maxOccurs attributes in the sequence tags from within an SSIS 2008 XML data source??
For example: `<xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="20">`

I am using such an XSD, and for some reason the 'Output name' dropdown in the 'Columns' tab of the XML Source Editor contains the various XSD elements suffixed with

> 'sequence_1', 'sequence_2', 'sequence_3', and so forth.

For example:

> 'ExportData__sequence_1' 
>   'ExportData__sequence_1__Quote' ...
>   'ExportData__sequence_2' 
>   'ExportData__sequence_2__Risk' ...

Removing the maxOccurs from the XSD removes these 'sequence' suffixes from the XML Source Editor. I've no idea of the reasons for this behaviour, but it is preventing the successful loading of XML data because the XML contains no such elements as

> 'ExportData__sequence_1__Quote' - the superfluous 'sequence_1'

causes the legitimate elements of 'ExportData__Quote' for example to be missed.

Can anybody shed any light on why SSIS 2008 would be doing this, and how to work around it WITHOUT modifying the XSD to remove the maxOccurs attributes??

Comment: If you're going to copy someone's [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20a58477-6b4b-477d-a7f5-cb73860d6d12/weird-behaviour-with-ssis-2008-and-xsds-with-maxoccurs-attributes?forum=sqlintegrationservices), at least provide a proper citation/link.

Comment: @kjhughes I'm having same problem here, I found this question which just explain my problem but nobody was able to answer it. so I hope the stackoverflows folks can answer it.